# LibGit2Sharp 0.25.x version does not work with .NetFramework 4.5

Tags: libgit2sharp

I get an error message after updating from 0.24.0 to 0.25.2. I get this error on .Net 4.0 Projects too.

Error message:

> Could not install package 'LibGit2Sharp 0.25.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.